# How to wire in gas boiler zone valves with out a zvc

Tags: wiring, thermostat, boiler, zoned-heating

Does anyone have a basic wiring schematic for wiring up 3 zone valves without a zone valve controller? They are honeywell zone valves. The boiler is brand new and everything is prewired.  It just needs the zone valves added in and 120v power. The boiler is a weil mclain gas boiler

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. It would be helpful if you were to [edit] your post to include the model of the boiler and the zone valves. Then, while you're waiting for an answer, take the [tour] and browse through the [help] to learn how to make the most of the site.

Comment: Knowing the brand is a good start. Do you have a model number? Boiler _and_ zone valves (for all of them if they happen to be different).